# Django ArrayField gives me syntax error at or near

Tags: django, django-models

I was implementing [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array/) using Python3, Django==1.9.9, psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.4, but if I do:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
*
*    
exceptions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), _('Exceptions'), default=list, help_text=exceptions_help_text)
```

I receive this error, full Traceback is attached here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 482, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 116, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 634, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/myproj/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Exceptions"
LINE 1: ..._wms" ALTER COLUMN "exceptions" TYPE varchar(200)[Exceptions...
```

While `makemigrations` works:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('owss', '0006_auto_20160826_1140'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='exceptions',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list, help_text='help text exceptions', size='Exceptions'),
        )
    ]
```

Is this a bug?

If not how can I set the field name?

Comment: Daviddd, provide full error message please.

Comment: @ivanperelivskiy checking the migration code, I see we have size='Exceptions', that it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the code you link to, the second positional argument is the size of the field, which is why Django is trying to pass it to Postgres which it wouldn't normally do with the name.

If you want to define the verbose name, pass it as a kwarg:

```
exceptions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), verbose_name=_('Exceptions'), default=...)
```

Comment: I got the same problem, but the migration created is correct: field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=200), default=list, help_text='help text exceptions', size=None, verbose_name='Exceptions'). Maybe the previous migration is blocking, trying to remove it.

Comment: I removed the incorrect migration and it works :-). Thanks!